How valid is this verse regarding chanting mantras for 108 times?
ashtottara-sataih purva pancasadbhis tu madhyama | kanyasi panca-vimsatya parimanam vidhiyate
“One round of Mantra Yoga should be either one hundred and eight (108)times which is the best, or fifty (50)times which is medium or twenty (20) times which is the lowest.”
From which scripture is it?


The ancient scriptures mention 108 energy lines or nadis converging to form the heart or anahata chakra. Chanting or doing meditation with mantras 108 times is believed to help align these energy lines, leading to spiritual awakening and self-realization.

Chanting mantras for 108 times is a common practice in many spiritual traditions, including Hinduism, Buddhism, and Jainism. The significance of the number 108 is rooted in ancient symbolism and spiritual beliefs:

Mathematical Significance: The number 108 has mathematical significance in various contexts. For example, it is divisible by the sum of its digits (1 + 0 + 8 = 9), and it is also divisible evenly by 12 and 27, making it a versatile and auspicious number.

Cosmic Connection: In Hinduism and other traditions, the number 108 is believed to represent the entire universe. It is said to correspond to the number of deities in the Hindu tradition, the number of sacred sites in India, the number of beads in a mala (prayer beads), and the distance between the Earth and the Sun, among other symbolic associations.

Spiritual Purification: Chanting mantras is considered a powerful spiritual practice for purifying the mind, body, and soul. By repeating a mantra 108 times, practitioners aim to deepen their focus, cultivate mindfulness, and connect with divine energies.

Ritualistic Tradition: Many spiritual rituals and ceremonies involve chanting mantras or performing certain actions 108 times as a form of devotion and reverence. This repetition is believed to create a sacred resonance and invite blessings from higher realms.


Overall, chanting mantras for 108 times is a sacred practice that carries deep spiritual significance and is believed to foster inner transformation, spiritual growth, and alignment with cosmic energies.
Update 1
Varaha Purana its chapter 128 verse 80. Here is pdf form of this Purana.
In the Varaha Purana, it is stated:

ashtottara-sataih purva pancasadbhis tu madhyama |
kanyasi panca-vimsatya parimanam vidhiyate ||73||

One round of Mantra Yoga should be either one hundred and eight (108)times which is the best, or fifty (50)times which is medium or twenty (20) times which is the lowest.
Reference link - https://level.game/blogs/is-it-safe-to-do-om-chanting-108-times?lang=en

Thanks for taking your time out but this does not answer my question. I had provided a verse and I want to know the source of the verse.

@AdityaMishra updated my answer, please check again,

Thanks! Can you specify the exact canto, chapter and verse number?

The provided reference is not supporting most of the opinions pointed. For example, the mathematical and scientific significances. Also random blog link is not authentic source. Please add citation for opinion which lacks authentic sources.
